# how to reload single row in tableview when we have different no of cells in tableview?

Tags: objective-c

i have a tableview in which there are 3 different cell...i want to load data of only second row so please help me how can i reload a particular single row of tableview in objective c?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: if you don't need animation just say `[tableview reloadData];`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
NSIndexPath* rowToReload = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:2 inSection:0];
NSArray* rowsToReload = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:rowToReload, nil];
[yourTableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:rowsToReload withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

hope this will helpful to you

Answer (score 0):

use `[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths: withRowAnimation:];`

*as :*

```
[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:arrayOfIndexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```